# How to create Database in Sqlite?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have downloaded sqlite-jdbc-3.72.jar and don't know where to place it so it executed my code using command line as

javac SQLiteJDBC.java

and i run it by using **java -classpath ".;sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar" SQLiteJDBC** (Windows)

**it gives exception as SQLite :: main :: org.sqlite.JDBC** and my code is below

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SQLiteJDBC
{
    public static void main(String ar[])
    {
        Connection c = null;

        try
        {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("SQLite :: main :: "+e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
    }


}
```

Comment: instead of `System.out.println("SQLite :: main :: "+e.getMessage())`, post the output of `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: ClassNotFoundException at class.forName()

Comment: Your classpath is incorrect, first of all it shouldn't be surrounded by quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look to : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

**Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath**

You may need to reference classes in other JAR files from within a JAR file.

For example, in a typical situation an applet is bundled in a JAR file whose manifest references a different JAR file (or several different JAR files) that serves as utilities for the purposes of that applet.

You specify classes to include in the Class-Path header field in the manifest file of an applet or application. The Class-Path header takes the following form:

```
Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name
```

So, in your case it would be something like

```
java -classpath sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar SQLiteJDBC
```

It should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your command as :

```
java -classpath ".:sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar" SQLiteJDBC
```